# uneven vertical spacing of radio buttons

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Is there a way to make the vertical spacing between radio buttons even?  If you look at the image, you can see that the vertical spacing is uneven, and it causes me great personal pain.  I thought it was because of the superscripts, so I put each and every button structure in a div and used CSS to set the height of those divs to so something large.  It didn't matter how tall I made the divs.  They did spread out vertically, but they remained unevenly spaced (like the narrow space between Quadratic and Inverse was *always* narrower than everything else).

[image: unevenly spaced radio buttons]

```css
.mathClass {
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 110%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: none;
}

.radioClass {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0 margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.radioMark {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 0;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #4C6A94;
}
```

```html
Models:
<form>
  <label class="radioClass"> None
            <input type="radio" onclick="computeAll()" name="usefit" id="fitNone" checked>
            <span class="radioMark"></span>
            </label>
  <label class="radioClass">  Exactly Proportional&#8239;:&nbsp&nbsp; <i class="mathClass">y = x</i>
            <input type="radio" class="radioClass" onclick="computeAll()" name="usefit" id="yEqualsX">
            <span class="radioMark"></span>
            </label>
  <label class="radioClass">  Proportional&#8239;:&nbsp&nbsp; <i class="mathClass">y = Ax</i>
            <input type="radio" class="radioClass" onclick="computeAll()" name="usefit" id="yEqualsAX">
            <span class="radioMark"></span>
            </label>
  <label class="radioClass"> Linear&#8239;:&nbsp;&nbsp;  <i class="mathClass">y = Ax + B </i>
            <input type="radio" onclick="computeAll()" name="usefit" id="fitLinear">
            <span class="radioMark"></span>
            </label>
  <label class="radioClass"> Square Law&#8239;:&nbsp;&nbsp;  <i class="mathClass">y = Ax<sup>2</sup></i>
            <input type="radio" onclick="computeAll()" name="usefit" id="fitSquare">
            <span class="radioMark"></span>
            </label>
  <label class="radioClass"> Quadratic&#8239;:&nbsp&nbsp;  <i class="mathClass">y = Ax<sup>2</sup> + Bx + C</i>
            <input type="radio" onclick="computeAll()" name="usefit" id="fitQuadratic">
            <span class="radioMark"></span>
            </label>
  <label class="radioClass"> Inverse&#8239;:&nbsp&nbsp; <i class="mathClass">y = A/x</i>
            <input type="radio" onclick="computeAll()" name="usefit" id="fitInverse">
            <span class="radioMark"></span>
            </label>
  <label class="radioClass"> Inverse Square&#8239;:&nbsp&nbsp; <i class="mathClass">y = A/x<sup>2</sup></i>
            <input type="radio" onclick="computeAll()" name="usefit" id="fitInverseSquare">
            <span class="radioMark"></span>
            </label>
```

Comment: Your code unravels different view than image... if you looking for only vertical alignment then I can get you a solution.

Comment: @Manjuboyz - The code shown is just a snippet out of a larger div that sits in a larger web page.  I only included the section where the problem is.  If HTML or CSS elsewhere on the page is responsible for the uneven line spacing here, then I will just give up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make the lines evenly spaced.  By examining the page carefully, I figured out that if label contains text with a superscript, then an extra 4 pixels of vertical padding are added to the label.  Putting each label in a fixed height div doesn't help, because the padding still shifts the label within the div.

The (completely and totally inelegant) fix was to manually add 4 pixels of top padding to the labels that don't contain superscripts.  I did this in the HTML with a style= because there are so many separate entries in the CSS associated with styling the radio buttons.  Creating separate classes for radio buttons with and without superscript labels and duplicating all that CSS seemed silly.